# working on specific characters in a string in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am new to python. I have used c before. There we can work character by character using indexing in string. I was trying to convert the whole string to lower case, reverse it and print it with first character in upper case

```
first_name = input("enter your first name\n")
last_name = input("enter your last name\n")
first_name = first_name.lower()
last_name = last_name.lower()
def rev(s):
 str = ""
 for i in s:
    str = i + str
    return str
first_name = rev(first_name)
last_name = rev(last_name)
first_name[0].upper()
last_name[0].upper()
print(first_name + " " + last_name)
```

The output is

enter your first name

Manash

enter your last name

Sharma

m s

Comment: Python allows string indexing as well.  See this answer for how to reverse a string using Python's string indexing: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `[::-1]` to reverse your string
- `str.capitalize` or `str.title` to get the first letter upper case

**Demo:**

```
first_name = input("enter your first name\n")
last_name = input("enter your last name\n")
first_name = first_name[::-1].capitalize()
last_name = last_name[::-1].capitalize()
```

Comment: no need for the `.lower()` call `.capitalize()` handles that

Comment: @Chris_Rands. Thanks.

Comment: But we were asked not to use any library functions. How can we achieve that without library functions.

Comment: @ManashSharma only default method are used here

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake lies in returning immediately inside the for loop, and in not assigning the capitalization:

```
first_name = input("enter your first name\n")
last_name = input("enter your last name\n")
first_name = first_name.lower()
last_name = last_name.lower()
def rev(s):
    str = ""
    for i in s:
       str = i + str
    return str
first_name = rev(first_name)
last_name = rev(last_name)
first_name = first_name[0].upper() + first_name[1:]
last_name = last_name[0].upper() + last_name[1:]
print(first_name + " " + last_name)
```

Note that there are of course nicer, quicker, and easier ways of doing this, as shown in the other answer.

Comment: File "3.py", line 12, in <module>
    first_name[0] = first_name[0].upper()
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Oops, you're right. You can't change strings, they are immutable. Fixed answer.